# Linux command to concatenate a file to itself n times

Tags: linux, concatenation

I've taken a plain text file book from Project Gutenberg (around 0.5MB) which I want to concatenate to itself `n` times in order to generate a large text file that I can benchmark some algorithms on.  Is there a linux command I can use to achieve this?  `cat` sounds ideal, but doesn't seem to play too nice with concatenating a file onto itself, plus does not directly address the `n` times part of the question.

Comment: use some kind of loop, and appending? so repeat foo.txt>>bar.txt and wrap that up in something that will run the command that many times?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Two parts to this, to me - first - to use cat to output the text file to standard output, and use append to add it to another file - eg foo.txt>>bar.txt will append foo.txt to bar.txt

then run it n times with

```
for i in {1..n};do cat foo.txt >> bar.txt; done
```

replacing n in that command with your number

should work, where n is your number

If you use csh, there's the 'repeat' command.

[repeat related parts of the answer are copied from here](http://www.stefanoforenza.com/how-to-repeat-a-shell-command-n-times/) , and i tested it on an ubuntu 11.04 system on the default bash shell.

Comment: Fun fact: this actually works without replacing 'n', in which case it'll execute the body once for each character between ASCII '1' and ASCII 'n' (so 62 times). But `{1..12}` will correctly run the body 12 times.

Comment: You might want to just redirect the whole pipeline, rather than appending in each iteration: `for i in {1..n};do cat foo.txt; done > bar.txt`

Comment: This doesn't give you the exponential growth size... :)

Answer (score 6):

You certainly can use `cat` for this:

```
$ cat /tmp/f
foo
$ cat /tmp/f /tmp/f
foo
foo
```

To get `$n` copies, you could use `yes` piped into `head -n $n`:

```
$ yes /tmp/f | head -n 10
/tmp/f
/tmp/f
/tmp/f
/tmp/f
/tmp/f
/tmp/f
/tmp/f
/tmp/f
/tmp/f
/tmp/f
```

Putting that together gives

```
yes /tmp/f | head -n $n | xargs cat >/tmp/output
```

Comment: You have just teached me two commands. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I am bored so here are a few more methods on how to concatenate a file to itself, mostly with `head` as a crutch. Pardon me if I overexplain myself, I just like saying things :P

---

Assuming `N` is the number of self concatenations you want to do and that your file is named `file`.

**Variables:**

```
linecount=$(<file wc -l)

total_repeats=$(echo "2^$N - 1" | bc) # obtained through the power of MATH

total_lines=$((linecount*(total_repeats+1)))

tmp=$(mktemp --suffix .concat.self)
```

Given a copy of `file` called `file2`, `total_repeats` is the number of times `file` would need to be added to `file2` to make it the same as if `file` was concatenated to itself `N` times.

Said **MATH** is here, more or less: [MATH (gist)](https://gist.github.com/fcard/339fcb8d7c1781c7fe1d8b86d645762b)

It's first semester computer science stuff but It's been a while since I did a induction proof so I can't get over it... (also this class of recursion is pretty well known to be `2^Loops` so there is that too....)

---

**POSIX**

I use a few non-posix things but they are not essential.
For my purposes:

```
 yes() { while true; do echo "$1"; done; }
```

Oh, I only used that. Oh well, the section is already here...

---

## Methods

---

`head` with linecount tracking.

```
ln=$linecount
for i in $(seq 1 $N); do
    <file head -n $ln >> file;
    ln=$((ln*2))
done
```

No temp file, no cat, not even too much math yet, all joy.

---

`tee` with **MATH**

```
<file tee -a file | head -n $total_lines > $tmp
cat $tmp > file
```

Here `tee` is reading from `file` but perpetually appending to it, so it will keep reading the file on repeat until `head` stops it. And we know when to stop it because of **MATH**. The appending goes overboard through, so I used a temp file. You could trim the excess lines from `file` too.

---

`eval`, the lord of darkness!

```
eval "cat $(yes file | head -n $((total_repeats+1)) | tr '\n' ' ')" > $tmp
cat $tmp > file
```

This just expands to `cat file file file ...` and evals it.
You can do it without the `$tmp` file, too:

```
eval "cat $(yes file | head -n $total_repeats | tr '\n' ' ')" |
  head -n $((total_lines-linecount)) >> file
```

The second `head` "tricks" `cat` by putting a middle man between it and the write operation. You could trick `cat` with another `cat` as well but that has  inconsistent behavior. Try this:

```
test_double_cat() {
    local Expected=0
    local Got=0
    local R=0
    local file="$(mktemp --suffix .double.cat)"
    for i in $(seq 1 100); do

        printf "" > $file
        echo "1" >> $file
        echo "2" >> $file
        echo "3" >> $file

        Expected=$((3*$(<file wc -l)))

        cat $file $file | cat >> $file

        Got=$(<file wc -l)

        [ "$Expected" = "$Got" ] && R="$((R+1))"
    done
    echo "Got it right $R/100"
    rm $file
}
```

---

`sed`:

```
<file tr '\n' '\0' |
    sed -e "s/.*/$(yes '\0' | head -n $total_repeats | tr -d '\n')/g" |
        tr '\0' '\n' >> file
```

Forces `sed` into reading the entire file as a line, captures all of it, then pastes it `$total_repeats` number of times.

This will fail of course if you have any null characters in your file. Pick one that you know isn't there.

```
find_missing_char() {
  local file="${1:-/dev/stdin}"

  firstbyte="$(<$file fold -w1 | od -An -tuC | sort -un | head -n 1)"
  if [ ! "$firstbyte" = "0" ]; then
    echo "\0"
  else
    printf "\\$(printf '%03o\t' $((firstbyte-1)) )"
  fi
}
```

---

That's all for now lads, I hope this arbitrary answer didn't bother anyone. I tested all of them many times but I am only a two-year shell user so keep that in mind I guess. Now to sleep...

`rm $tmp`

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use `tee` for this.  `tee -a x x` will append the same lines twice to file `x`.

Now we need to write `x` *$N* times.  We can do that with `yes x|head -n $N`, giving

```
<file tee -a $(yes outfile|head -n $N)
```

Demo:

```
$ cat foo
foo
bar
$ tee -a $(yes x|head -5) <foo >/dev/null
$ cat x
foo
bar
foo
bar
foo
bar
foo
bar
foo
bar
```

Answer (score 0):

#### For files with headers

```python
!cat sample.csv > large.txt # first write with header
!for i in {1..200}; do tail -n +2 sample.csv >> large.txt; done
```

-n +2 starts output from 2nd line